# Как выстроить div-ы в ряд?

Tags: css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, html

Есть набор из 6 блоков.
Задача стоит в том, чтобы выстроить три первых в первой колонке, а оставшиеся три - во второй колонке?

```css
      .container{
                        background: #333;
                        
                    }
                    .container .first-block {
                        background: yellow;
                        width: 50%;
                        height: 50%;
                        padding: 5px;
                        margin: 5px;
                        min-height: 150px;
                    }
                    .container .second-block {
                        background: green;
                        width: 50%;
                        height: 50%;
                        padding: 5px;
                        margin: 5px;
                        min-height: 150px;
                    }
                    .container .third-block {
                        background: purple;
                        width: 50%;
                        height: 50%;
                        padding: 5px;
                        margin: 5px;
                        min-height: 150px;
                    }
                    .container .fourth-block {
                        background: blue;
                        width: 50%;
                        height: 50%;
                        padding: 5px;
                        margin: 5px;
                        min-height: 150px;
                    }
                    .container .fifth-block {
                        background: black;
                        width: 50%;
                        height: 50%;
                        padding: 5px;
                        margin: 5px;
                        min-height: 150px;
                    }

                     .container .six-block {
                        background: red;
                        width: 50%;
                        height: 50%;
                        padding: 5px;
                        margin: 5px;
                    }


                    .clear {
                     clear: both;
                    }

                    .container .first-column {
                        width: 70%;
                    }

                    .container .second-column {
                        width: 30%;
                    }
```

```html
 <div class="container">

            <div class="first-column">

                <div class="first-block">1</div>
                <div class="second-block">2</div>
                <div class="third-block">3</div>

            </div>
   
            <div class="second-column">

                <div class="fourth-block">4</div>
                <div class="fifth-block">5</div>
                <div class="six-block">6</div>
                <div class="clear"></div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

При "сжимании" браузера нужно применить адаптивную вёрстку, так, чтобы все блоки были друг по другом, в одну колонку.

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

```css
      .container{
                        background: #333;
                        
                    }
                    .container .first-block {
                        background: yellow;
                        width: 45%;
                        padding: 5px;
                        margin: 5px;
                        min-height: 150px;
                    }
                    .container .second-block {
                        background: green;
                        width: 45%;
                        padding: 5px;
                        margin: 5px;
                        min-height: 150px;
                    }
                    .container .third-block {
                        background: purple;
                        width: 45%;
                        padding: 5px;
                        margin: 5px;
                        min-height: 150px;
                    }
                    .container .fourth-block {
                        background: blue;
                        width: 40%;
                        padding: 5px;
                        margin: 5px;
                        min-height: 150px;
                    }
                    .container .fifth-block {
                        background: black;
                        width: 40%;
                        padding: 5px;
                        margin: 5px;
                        min-height: 150px;
                    }

                     .container .six-block {
                        background: red;
                        width: 40%;
                        padding: 5px;
                        margin: 5px;
                    }


                    .clear {
                     clear: both;
                    }

                    .container .first-column {
                        width: 70%;

                        float:left;
                    }

                    .container .second-column {
                        width: 30%;

                        float:left;
                    }
```

```html
 <div class="container">

            <div class="first-column">

                <div class="first-block">1</div>
                <div class="second-block">2</div>
                <div class="third-block">3</div>

            </div>
   
            <div class="second-column">

                <div class="fourth-block">4</div>
                <div class="fifth-block">5</div>
                <div class="six-block">6</div>
                <div class="clear"></div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

В одну колонку - установить `min-width` или использовать `@media`

Comment: min-width - в какое место кода ставить? и значение в пикселах (примерно) какое?

Comment: ставить в стиль `first-column`. Значение - 70% от размера перехода (раз уж выбрано 70% ширины)